# Xamarin authentification - IUser depreciated, problem migrating to IAccount

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms

I'm at the end of my first Xamarin Forms app (Whoop!), and at the stage where I'm learning about authentication and linking it to Azure.

I've downloaded the best example I can find, here: [link to Xamarin Azure Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/xamarin-azure-businessreview)

I plan to go through the IdentityService.cs file and work out how it works.

Unfortunately there has been a recent depreciation as explained here: [msal net 2 released](https://aka.ms/msal-net-2-released)

I have changed as much as I can understand but still have two errors:

```
msalResult = await msaClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes,

IdentityService.GetUserByPolicy(msaClient.GetAccountsAsync(),

SignUpAndInPolicy), UIBehavior.ForceLogin, null, null, Authority, UIParent);
```

This is showing an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'   Reviewer.Core   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\snppts\xam-az-bw\src\Reviewer.Core\Services\IdentityService.cs   54  Active

And:

```
public void Logout()
    {
        foreach (var user in msaClient.GetAccountsAsync())
        {
            msaClient.Remove(user);
        }
    }
```

This is showing the following related error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Task>' because 'Task>' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' Reviewer.Core   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\snppts\xam-az-bw\src\Reviewer.Core\Services\IdentityService.cs   120 Active

The two problems, I suspect, have the same root cause. Can Anyone help me extract the accounts in the correct way? I do not want to fiddle much more with the original and I'm basically tinkering with an authentication process I do not understand yet in the first place!

Here is the full files code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Reviewer.Core;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IdentityService))]
namespace Reviewer.Core
{
    public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
    {
        static readonly string Tenant = "b2cbuild.onmicrosoft.com";
        static readonly string ClientID = "adc26e3b-2568-4007-810d- 6cc94e7416de";

        static readonly string SignUpAndInPolicy = "B2C_1_Reviewer_SignUpIn";
        static readonly string AuthorityBase = 
$"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
        static readonly string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase} 
 {SignUpAndInPolicy}";
        static readonly string[] Scopes = { 
"https://b2cbuild.onmicrosoft.com/reviewer/rvw_all" };
        static readonly string RedirectUrl = $"msal{ClientID}://auth";

    readonly PublicClientApplication msaClient;

    public IdentityService()
    {
        msaClient = new PublicClientApplication(ClientID);
        msaClient.ValidateAuthority = false;
        msaClient.RedirectUri = RedirectUrl;
    }

    UIParent parent;
    public UIParent UIParent { get => parent; set => parent = value; }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Login()
    {
        AuthenticationResult msalResult = null;

        // Running on Android - we need UIParent to be set to the main Activity
        if (UIParent == null && Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            return msalResult;

        // First check if the token happens to be cached - grab silently
        msalResult = await GetCachedSignInToken();

        if (msalResult != null)
            return msalResult;

        // Token not in cache - call adb2c to acquire it
        try
        {
            msalResult = await msaClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes,
                                                       IdentityService.GetUserByPolicy(msaClient.GetAccountsAsync(),
                                                                       SignUpAndInPolicy),
                                                       UIBehavior.ForceLogin,
                                                       null,
                                                       null,
                                                       Authority,
                                                       UIParent);
            if (msalResult?.Account.HomeAccountId != null)
            {
                var parsed = ParseIdToken(msalResult.IdToken);
                DisplayName = parsed["name"]?.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (MsalServiceException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == MsalClientException.AuthenticationCanceledError)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User cancelled");
            }
            else if (ex.ErrorCode == "access_denied")
            {
                // most likely the forgot password was hit
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Forgot password");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return msalResult;
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetCachedSignInToken()
    {
        try
        {
            // This checks to see if there's already a user in the cache
            var authResult = await msaClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes,
                                                           IdentityService.GetUserByPolicy(msaClient.GetAccountsAsync(),
                                                                           SignUpAndInPolicy),
                                                           Authority,
                                                           false);
            if (authResult?.User != null)
            {
                var parsed = ParseIdToken(authResult.IdToken);
                DisplayName = parsed["name"]?.ToString();
            }

            return authResult;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            // happens if the user hasn't logged in yet & isn't in the cache
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        foreach (var user in msaClient.GetAccountsAsync())
        {
            msaClient.Remove(user);
        }
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    IAccount GetUserByPolicy(IEnumerable<IAccount> users, string policy)
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            string userIdentifier = Base64UrlDecode(user.HomeAccountId.Identifier.Split('.')[0]);

            if (userIdentifier.EndsWith(policy.ToLower(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return user;
        }

        return null;
    }

    string Base64UrlDecode(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        s = s.PadRight(s.Length + (4 - s.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
        var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
        var decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Count());
        return decoded;
    }

    JObject ParseIdToken(string idToken)
    {
        // Get the piece with actual user info
        idToken = idToken.Split('.')[1];
        idToken = Base64UrlDecode(idToken);
        return JObject.Parse(idToken);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I think that you are missing an `await` in front of msaClient.GetAccountsAsync()

```
msalResult = await msaClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes,
      IdentityService.GetUserByPolicy(await msaClient.GetAccountsAsync(),
                                      SignUpAndInPolicy),     
      UIBehavior.ForceLogin, null, null, Authority, UIParent);
```

and

```
public void Logout()
{
 var accounts = await msaClient.GetAccountsAsync();
 foreach (var account in accounts)
 {
  msaClient.RemoveAsync(account);
  accounts = await msaClient.GetAccountsAsync();
 }
}
```

(which is really a `ClearCache()`)

I suggest you have a look at this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native, which has the updated code already

Comment: Merci Jean-Marc, je jetterai un coup d’oeil demain!

Comment: That's the one! Went through your sample and got it working (Sign up, signin Call API). Parfait! Transferred my Azure details into the sample and can sign in, out, up but!! Call API not working (error 401) . Any ideas? Start a new question? Thanks again for pointer above.

Comment: One thing occurs to me, I have used B2Clogin.com for requests in policy settings as Azure suggested due to depreciation of login.microsoftonline.com but the apps AuthorityBase is $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/". Maybe something to do with it. I have noticed I am so slow understanding things, by the time I have, it has depreciated... may also be something to do with it ;-)

Comment: @Mark we are currently working on enabling B2Cloging.com. See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/669. Meanwhile please use $"login.microsoftonline.com/tfp{Tenant}/".